# QProcess fails with specific commands

Tags: windows, qt, windows-10, qt5

I'm playing around with QProcess.execute() but fail at somethign quite simple. When calling

```
QProcess proc;
ret=proc.execute("Notepad.exe");
```

this works properly. But when I do the same with

```
QProcess proc;
ret=proc.execute("DisplaySwitch.exe");
```

proc.execute() returns a -2. Amazingly DisplaySwitch.exe is located at exactly the same position as Notepad.exe - and when I execute it out of command line, it works properly. So any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Use start() (execute () is static, `proc` is completely unused), read stdout/stderr and check all the possible errors.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld start() does not change anything and neither in stderr nor in stdout something can be found afterwards...

Comment: Até you waiting for the process to complete? Now that start() is asynchronous.

Comment: are you in a different directory? Some programs have trouble starting if you start them from a different working directory.

Comment: I'm in a different directory but this should not be a problem as I'm also in a different directory for the call to notepad.exe - which works properly.

Comment: Notepad.exe is in standard path too, might be that one would be executing.
-2 probably means "No such file or directory", please try giving absolute path of the .exe file

Comment: The dircetory can have an effect if the exe does some non-standard DLL-Loading. So please try it from command line to rule that thing out. Just go in another directory in the commandline and try runnging the exe from there.